# Excel: Is it possible to reorder the data in 2 columns to match up if they have a certain number of characters / a string in common?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently re-ordering massive amounts of media files and trying to conform them to a logging system.
I have 2 lists now, one is a list of all the URLs that the videos have been ripped from.

The other are the .mp4 filenames from the bulk download.

Column A looks like

```
C:\Users\XXX\BIN\MEDIA\1614561651289915393_2.mp4
C:\Users\XXX\BIN\MEDIA\1615390470523191305_2.mp4
C:\Users\XXX\BIN\MEDIA\1612041791171084288_2.mp4
C:\Users\XXX\BIN\MEDIA\1612425997130911747_2.mp4
```

Column B looks like:

```
https://twitter.com/user/status/1611717485828489221?s=12&t=HFVIWyICVNxavFltOixxVg
https://twitter.com/user/status/1612425997130911747?s=12&t=gU4QIpi1peMHASLbiRGKjA
https://twitter.com/user/status/1612831672805855232?s=12&t=IQ_M-PpP05ylmIRsBjlIfg
https://twitter.com/user/status/1604835107759853568?s=12&t=wzY0CTl6lyINeaFxisyZcQ
```

I want to reorder column A so that entries match up with the corresponding URL that contains the filename between /status/ and ?s=12&t.

Does that make sense / is that possible?

Thanks!

I tried match and v lookup but it only gives me a true / false. Would appreciate any help here :)

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and how you want the columns reordered? The easiest way may be to use helper columns

Comment: And please add your Excel version - this might make a difference ....

Comment: This is a perfect job for an `INDEX` and `MATCH` combo. [See here to get you started](https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match)

Comment: Hey, sorry new to this space, and was trying to anonymize the data a bit. Re: Excel version 2212 (Home & Office Student 2016). In the middle of something but will repost better data shortly!

Comment: Hmmm According to MS, v2212 is a version of Office 365, but you also reference 2016. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach - same result :-)

```
=LET(files,A1:A4,
URLs,B1:B4,
f,BYROW(files,LAMBDA(r,TEXTSPLIT(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(r,"\"),,-1),"_"))),
XLOOKUP("*/" & f &"~?*",URLs,URLs,"not found",2))
```

Compared to JvdVs solution, this one is independant of the number of subfolders of the path.

Comment: A small note; better to escape the wildcard with a tilde. `~?*` to actually match a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you have provided us the best possible sample data. Just one of these values in column A seem to have a match:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=XLOOKUP("*/"&LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"\",5),19)&"~?*",B1:B4,B1:B4,"Not Found",2)
```

Or, vice versa:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=XLOOKUP("*\"&LEFT(TEXTAFTER(B1:B4,"/",5),19)&"_*",A1:A4,A1:A4,"Not Found",2)
```